# Exception when using [] operator on a Data instance

Tags: swift

This little Swift snippet crashes Xcode 9.2 playgrounds on the last assignment, event though buffer still holds 23 bytes. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
import Cocoa

var str = "01234567890123456789012345678901234567"
var buffer = Data()

if let data = str.data(using: .utf8) {
   buffer.append(data)
   buffer = buffer[15..<38]
   buffer = buffer[2..<23]
}
```

Comment: If there's a crash, you should include a crash log in your question. How can we know what's going on otherwise, other than guessing?

Comment: @Caleb Normally I agree but the posted code is a valid MCV easily pasted in a playground so no guessing is required.

Comment: @rmaddy People may read SO on machines where they don't have ready access to Xcode. I don't think it's too much to ask the OP to do the work once so that everybody reading the question doesn't have to run the code just to find out what's going on. The very title of the question says there's an exception, but the OP doesn't even bother to tell us *what* exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is caused by either an SDK bug or an compiler optimization, both trying to avoid unnecessary data copies (aka copy-on-write). Setting a breakpoint on the problematic line and inspecting the `buffer` reveals something like this:

[image]

So the buffer points to the same data storage, but a different slice, and trying to access outside the slice causes the crash.

Changing the problematic line to `buffer = buffer[17..<38]` makes the crash go away.

I don't know why subscripting by range results in a `Data` that might lead to crashes if used in another (possibly unrelated) parts of the code that don't know they are dealing with a slice. Other collections, like `Array` have dedicated slice types for which you can expect to be have various valid indices.

Here's a naive example to support the above thought:

```
func printFirstByte(of data: Data) {
    print(data[0])
}

let str = "01234567890123456789012345678901234567"
if let data = str.data(using: .utf8) {
    printFirstByte(of: data[15..<38]) // this call crashes
}
```

On the other hand, we do have a [startIndex](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/1780121-startindex) and an [endIndex](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/1779752-endindex) property on the `Data` type, however this just makes it harder to work with `Data` instances, because it's not obvious that we need to zero-base the `Data` slice before sending it to old code that doesn't know about this behaviour.

Comment: I really don't think this is a bug. It is designed behavior of slices. While the last line is one valid solution, creating a new `Data` instance as @dasblinkenlight suggested is another option that allows you to use the desired (and expected?) range.

Comment: @rmaddy I took the possibility of a bug in consideration as assigning the buffer variable to a new slice should make the indexed operations relative to that slice (IMO).

Comment: But evidence and the documentation at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/2945721-subscript seem to indicate that your assumption is incorrect. It seems that indexes of slices still stay relative to the original collection.

Comment: @rmaddy the subscript documentation for [Data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/1779919-subscript) says that it returns a `Data` instance, while for collections we get a `SubSequence`. So something fishy, either the documentation is incorrect, or the implementation is.

Comment: The documentation for `Data subscript(Range)` shows the return value is not `Data` but a slice.

Comment: @rmaddy are we looking at the same documentation? :) The link I posted in my previous comment says nothing about sliced. Though maybe I'm looking at the wrong page :)

Comment: @Cristik `SubSequence` is an associated type on the `Collection` protocol, `Data` is its own slice, so it satisfies the requirement with `Data` – i.e `Data.SubSequence == Data`.

Comment: @rmaddy Still there's a slight difference between having a dedicated type, like `ArraySlice` and using the same one. Unless the slice get's it's indices reseted when the instance is passed around you might end up with unexpected crashes in unrelated places in code, due to this subtle behaviour.

Comment: @Cristik OK, it seems that somehow I found my way to some other subscript documentation and not the one specifically shown for `Data`. So now I'm more confused.

Comment: @Cristik Sure, I agree the behaviour is somewhat non-obvious and `Data` might well benefit from having a different slice type like `Array` does (though that would increase the frequency that it would need to be copied when having to pass a slice onto something expecting a `Data`). Another option would be to give it non-integer indices, though the ergonomics of slicing such a collection isn't currently great (just look at `String`).

Comment: So that means that we *never* can assume that the indices of some `Data` value start at zero? Even for things like `String.data(using:)` or `CBCharacteristic.value` ?

Comment: @MartinR Correct (though it seems unlikely for the specific cases you mention) – might be worth bringing up on Swift evolution as I'm sure there's plenty of people that aren't aware of this, and the API can almost certainly be better designed to avoid this very easy potential for misuse.

Comment: There's some discussion on this behaviour in the comments of https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5300